# Why do I get NaN in working with this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to improve my JS with the Book Eloquent Javascript.  I was working on the solution to [question 5.2](http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#5.2) and would love some explianation as to why it was wrong and return NaN.  My Solution was :

```
function average(array) {
  function plus(a, b) { return a + b; }
  return array.reduce(plus) / array.length;
}

var byName = {};
ancestry.forEach(function(person) {
  byName[person.name] = person;
});

var knownMothers = ancestry.filter(function(person){
  return person.mother != null;
});

var ageDifferences = knownMothers.map(function(person){
  return person.born - [person.mother].born

});

console.log(knownMothers);
console.log(ageDifferences);
console.log(average(ageDifferences));
```

The last two console.log statemets return NaN.

ancestry is an array formatted like this:

```
[0: {
    name:   "Carolus Haverbeke"
    sex:    "m"
    born:   1832
    died:   1905
    father: "Carel Haverbeke"
    mother: "Maria van Brussel"
}
1:  {
    name:   "Emma de Milliano"
    sex:    "f"
    born:   1876
    died:   1956
    father: "Petrus de Milliano"
    mother: "Sophia van Damme"
}]
```

The solution is to this exercise is located in the above link.  It makes use of the byName object in the code, and as such bypasses getting NaN in the output.  Could someone please clarify why I need to return elements inside the byName object? I know its the missing piece but don't know WHY and really want to understand.  Thank you!

I copied the answer(I don't quite understand) below for reference:

```
var differences = ancestry.filter(function(person) {
  return byName[person.mother] != null;
}).map(function(person) {
  return person.born - byName[person.mother].born;
});

console.log(average(differences));
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `[person.mother].born` to do?

Comment: I know its wrong but I was expecting it access the key for `[person.mother]` and then get the .born value for that respective mother.  I see now that I wouldn't necessarily be able access the values that way and I would need to go through the byName object to get  the born year.   Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your definition of `ageDifferences` lacks a reference to `byName`. (And a safe-guard against `byName[person.mother]` not being set.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here,

```
return person.born - [person.mother].born
```

person.born is a number &
[person.mother] is supposed to be array (since []) (as per your definition). and [person.mother].born should be a number too (as per requirement). So, you cannot use [person.mother].born, you should find value for "person.mother" key in your object.

When you do this,

```
console.log(average(ageDifferences));
```

method 'average' is meant for taking array of number as parameter.

Since, ageDifferences is not having number as element, its giving NaN error.

Answer (score 0):

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bupuhu/1/edit?js,console)

The reason for `NaN` is you are trying to subtract person.born - person.mother.born where second operand doesn't even exit. So it's Number - undefined. So you are getting NaN.

And for knownMothers, you are equating it to null which may not match all conditions. Also You need to update the `knownMothers` filter. You need to check both whether the person has a mother and also whether the mother name is present int he byName object as well. Like below:

```
var knownMothers = ancestry.filter(function(person){
          return person.mother && byName[person.mother];
        });
```

Once you do that, you would be able to get the ageDifference and average.

```
   var ancestry = [{
        name:   "Carolus Haverbeke",
        sex:    "m",
        born:   1832,
        died:   1905,
        father: "Carel Haverbeke",
        mother: "Maria van Brussel"
    },  {
        name:   "Emma de Milliano",
        sex:    "f",
        born:   1876,
        died:   1956,
        father: "Petrus de Milliano"
    }, {
      name : "Maria van Brussel",
      sex:    "m",
        born:   1782,
        died:   1905,
        father: "Carel Haverbeke",
        mother: "Maria van"
    }];
    function average(array) {
      function plus(a, b) { return a + b; }
      return array.reduce(plus) / array.length;
    }

    var byName = {};
    ancestry.forEach(function(person) {
      byName[person.name] = person;
    });
    var knownMothers = ancestry.filter(function(person){
      return person.mother && byName[person.mother];
    });
    var ageDifferences = knownMothers.map(function(person){
      return person.born - byName[person.mother].born;
      // assumption: you are trying to get mother's born year from the byName object
    });

    console.log(knownMothers);
    console.log(ageDifferences);
    console.log(average(ageDifferences));
```